# Primefaces dialog doesn't close the second time

Tags: primefaces, dialog

I use a dialog to show newsletters. The first time, everything goes ok: the dialog pops up and it can be closed using the X and using the extra button 'close'

```
            <h:form id="frmDialog">
            <p:dialog header="...: NEWS :..."
                      widgetVar="widgetInfo" modal="true" dynamic="true"> 
                <p:commandButton  value="close" onclick="widgetInfo.hide();"/>
                <p:outputPanel id="pnlNewsLetter" style="width:610px;">                                        
                    <ui:include src="#{corporateManager.newsLetter}"/>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
```

....
When I click the button to reopen the same dialog, it opens, but can't be closed. In stead of closing, hitting the X button or the 'close' button, the entire content of the dialog gets selected and the page becomes inresponsive
.....

```
          <h:form>
            <h:commandButton  image="/newsletters/img/1karel.png" onclick="widgetInfo.show();">
            <f:ajax render=":frmDialog:pnlNewsLetter"/>
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="/newsletters/2012-12-21.html" target="#{corporateManager.newsLetter}"/>
         </h:commandButton></h:form>
```

..... i've tried using p:commandButton, using oncomplete(), closable="false", used h:button, added/removed form-tags or id's etc...

Environment: Glasfish3.1.2 - Netbeans 7.3 - Primefaces 3.1 - Google Chrome 27.0.1453.94 m

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to another post I've missed yesterday: [dialog will not close primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644108/dialog-will-not-close-primefaces?rq=1) , 
I've changed my code and it runs as expected, showing for each button another newsletter:

```
<p:commandButton   oncomplete="widgetInfo.show();" value="" styleClass="karel4"
      update=":pnlNewsLetter">
 <f:setPropertyActionListener value="/newsletters/2013-03-19.html" target="#{corporateManager.newsLetter}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

I had to remove `<f:ajax render=":pnlNewsLetter"/>` because otherwise the first newsletter was shown even when another button was clicked.
Many Thanks!